# Consider the groups $\mathbb{S_4}$, $\mathbb{D_6 \times C_2}$ and $\mathbb{A_4 \times C_2}$. Are of any of these two isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Consider the groups $\mathbb{S_4}$, $\mathbb{D_6 \times C_2}$ and $\mathbb{A_4 \times C_2}$. Are of any of these two isomorphic?

I tried looking at the size of the groups to eliminate possibilities, however, they're all size 24. I would really appreciate any help on this question.

Comment: You could list the possible orders of elements in each group, for a start...or the commutation properties. For example, in the second and  third one, you can find an element of order 3 commuting with an element of order two. Can this happen with the first one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly $S_4$ is not isomorphic to $A_4\times C_2$, since the first group has trivial center, the second however not. Also $D_6\times C_2$ has non-trivial center. Furthermore it is easy to see that $A_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_6$ by considering the element orders. In fact, $D_6$ has an element of order $6$, but $A_4$ doesn't. Hence all three groups are different, but all have order $24$.

Comment: Probably a little more detail would be required to conclude that $A_4$ not isomorphic to $D_6$ is enough.

Comment: @verret Since $A_4$ has no elements of order $6$, it cannot be isomorphic to $D_6$, which has a rotation of order $6$. Hence $D_6\times C_2$ cannot be isomorphic to $A_4\times C_2$. What more detail do you want?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're using the fact that $H\not\cong G$ implies $H\times C_2\not\cong G\times C_2$ which is harder than proving that these two groups of order $24$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: Assuming that $D_6$ means the dihedral group of order $6$ (so that all groups have order 24), then $D_6\times C_2$ does not have an element of order $12$.

Comment: There are two conflicting notation for dihedral groups. Some people use $D_6$ for the dihedral group of order $6$ (isomorphic to $S_3$), others for the dihedral group of order $12$. In the question you link, they are using the first convention. Using the second convention, we have $D_3\times C_2\cong D_6$, but $D_6\times C_2\not\cong D_{12}$.

Comment: Moreover, it is easy to compute the order of elements in direct product, and you can check by inspection that $D_6\times C_2$ has no element of order $12$. (In fact, that's one very easy way to check that $D_6\times C_2\not\cong D_{12}$).

Comment: Even then it is not difficult to distinguish $A_4\times C_2$ and $D_6\times C_2$, e.g., by its center.

Comment: Sure, I was only pointing out that the current answer is misleading.